# How to check that all elements of an array are defined in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

```perl6
> so (Any)
False
```

But

```perl6
> so [1, Any]
True
```

How to make it produce `False`?

**UPD:** This seems to work, though I'm not sure it's the right way.

```perl6
> so [1, Any].all
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want definedness rather than truthyness checks, you can also `say [1, 2, Any].all.defined`, which will autothread the defined method call over the junction.

```
say [1, 2, True].all.defined   # True
say [1, Int, True].all.defined # False
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `(Any)` is *not* a `List`, `(Any,)` *is* (note the comma).  You should either make the first case an array (like `[Any]`).  Otherwise you're comparing apples with oranges :-)

When you give `so` a list (lowercase list meaning an `Array` or a `List` in this context), it will take the number of elements in the list: so every list that has at least one element, will give True.

To answer your question, there are many ways of doing that, but all will require at least partial walking of the list.  If you are sure that your list does not contain `0` or the empty string, you could do something as simple as:

```
say so [&&] (1,Any,3); # False
say so [&&] (1,2,3);   # True
```

The `[&&]` is basically saying: `1 && Any && 3` and `1 && 2 && 3`.

If you cannot be sure of that, then you will have to do an additional step:

```
say [&&] (1,Any,3).map: *.defined; # False
say [&&] (1,0,3).map: *.defined;   # True
```

Note that in this case you don't have to do the `so`, as the `.map` already makes the values either `True` or `False`.  I'm leaving it as an exercise for the reader to do something faster using `.first`.

Comment: Thanks! I've forgotten that `so 0 == False`.

Comment: Indeed, fixed.  Thanks!